# Cocoa Screensaver Framework error message

Tags: cocoa, macos, screensaver

I'm trying to make a screen saver using the cocoa screensaver framework. The project builds fine and generates the .saver file, but when I try to run it in the preferences test window, it displays the error message:

"You cannot use the  screen saver with this version of Mac OSX. Please contact the vendor to get a newer version of the screen saver"

I have the xcode settings to Release | x86_64, and I am running OSX 10.6.6 on a 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5 Macbook Pro. I've searched around online, and most of the solutions to this error message seem addressed to making sure the build is 64-bit, which the x86_64 setting should indeed take care of. I am trying to play a QT movie in the screensaver, if that makes any difference.

I am at a loss, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Garbage Collector settings is set to at least "Supported". A lot of hosted frameworks will now require this setting - for instance Preference Panels need to be at least at "Supported" or it will cause System Preferences to restart its self (as with 32bit)

Comment: Only 64 bit required GC and only on 10.7. 10.8 reverts to "unsupported".

Comment: @geowar Correct, now that GC is deprecated, this comment no longer applies :)